# force download with hidden form not working

Tags: php, javascript, download, hidden-field

I am trying to force download a file with a javascript string called 'Proof'. I created a hidden form that triggers an action from a php script. The reason I am not using window.location.href is because the variable Proof is long and the get method could not handle it.

// Upon clicking the button save

```
$("#save").click(function () {
    var Proof = $("#main").html();
    var url = '/download-to-file.php';
    //send request
    jQuery('<form action="'+ url +'" method="post">'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="Proof" value="'+ Proof +'" />'+
    '</form>').appendTo('body').submit().remove();

 });
```

The php code:

```
<?php
$Proof = $_POST["Proof"];
$proof = stripslashes($Proof);

$file = 'savedproof.txt';


file_put_contents($file, $proof);
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
header("Content-Type: text/txt");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-length: '.filesize($file));  
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');

readfile($file);
?>
```

I get a download dialogue but the file is empty. I even tried with a smaller string like 'test' and still was empty so I am guessing that the hidden form's value is not working.

Thanks

Comment: are you getting any error in your log file?

Comment: are you sure you got the permission to write over the file? moreover.. is the $Proof variabile not empty? what's the need to write over a file if the output is what you get from the form?

Comment: The variable is not empty i checked with alert(Proof) and it contains html code. For writing permissions, I tried the suggestion below and it didn't work, no download dialogue appeared even. I am simply trying to let the user download the main div of the website as a text file. This main div was dynamically generated by the user. He then would be able to load it later if he wants to.

Comment: @pregmatch I get no errors after each click I simply get 
[06:18:45.971] POST http://www.proof-editor.host-ed.me/download-to-file.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 832ms]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if `file_put_contents` is failing but technically there is no need to write the data to a file since its already in $_POST.

Try changing the code to this and see if it works:

```
<?php
$Proof = stripslashes($_POST["Proof"])

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="savedproof.txt"');
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
header('Content-length: '.strlen($Proof));  
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');

echo $Proof;
```

Comment: I tried your code, and it just redirects me to .../download-to-file.php with a blank page and there is a console error : "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. @ ..../download-to-file.php"

Comment: I removed the content-transfer-encoding header you had, see if that helps.  Is the proof HTML or plain text?  If its html, you can try `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` for the content-type header.

Comment: Thanks, it worked when i added the extra headers and the content-type. However, there is some issue with quotations but that's for me to fix, at least there is some content in the file. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem.  Maybe the stripslashes isn't necessary?  Or is it just that the HTML entities `&quot;` need to be translated to `"`?  If that's the case then [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) should be of use.